# Aggregation of multiple rows into one

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

This is how the data looks like:

```
   master_id id states
    1         1  NJ, PA, IL
    1         2  IL, NJ, NY, CA
    1         3  MA, DC
```

I am trying to pull a summary of states at the `master_id` level (notice the removal of duplication for NJ and IL), ie.:

```
master_id states
1         NJ, PA, IL, NY, CA, MA, DC
```

Any suggestions how I can do it? Of course this needs to be dynamic for all such cases, these states are just an example.

Comment: You should show some sort of attempt that you have tried to make. And if the states are stored like that in your table, that is a poor design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To join them together, you want listagg:

```
select master_id, listagg(states, ', ') as states
from MyTable
group by master_id;
```

But first we split them, and to remove those duplicates we use a distinct:

```
select master_id, listagg(distinct new_state, ', ') as states
from
(
  select master_id, TRIM(SPLIT_PART(states,',', 1)) as new_state
  from mytable
) x1
group by master_id
```

And I guess you want the ordered? Ok, let's do that:

```
select master_id, 
       listagg(distinct new_state, ', ')
         within group (order by new_state) as states
from
(
  select master_id, TRIM(SPLIT_PART(states,',', 1)) as new_state
  from mytable
) x1
group by master_id
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you

Comment: Question, is there a listagg(distinct) over()? I actually have too many variables, and I don't want to group by all 20+ of them?

Comment: @user8834780 In that case, do the listagg grouped by the master_id, then join it to the rest of your data